# Is there a Python Pipeline function for running multiple Classifiers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline

As a general rule of thumb, it is required to run baseline models on the dataset. I know [H2O- AutoML](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o-tutorials/latest-stable/h2o-world-2017/automl/index.html) and other AUtoML packages do this. But I want to try using Scikit-learn Pipeline,

Here is what I have done so far,

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, make_scorer
import os
rs = {'random_state': 42}

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, train_size=0.6, **rs)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test, = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, train_size=0.5, **rs)
```

```
# Classification - Model Pipeline
def train_models(X_train, X_val, X_test, y_train, y_val, y_test):
    log_reg = LogisticRegression(**rs)
    nb = BernoulliNB()
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
    svm = SVC(**rs)
    mlp = MLPClassifier(max_iter=5000, **rs)
    dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(**rs)
    et = ExtraTreesClassifier(**rs)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(**rs)
    xgb = XGBClassifier(**rs, verbosity=0)
    scorer = make_scorer(f1_score)

    clfs = [('Logistic Regression', log_reg), ('Naive Bayes', nb),
            ('K-Nearest Neighbors', knn), ('SVM', svm), 
            ('MLP', mlp), ('Decision Tree', dt), ('Extra Trees', et), 
            ('Random Forest', rf), ('XGBoost', xgb)]
    pipelines = []
    scores_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Model', 'Val_Score', 'F1_Score'])
    test_scores = []
    for clf_name, clf in clfs:
        pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
            ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
            ('classifier', clf)])
        pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
        val_score = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_val, y_val, scoring=scorer, cv=3).mean()
        print(f'{clf_name}\n{"-" * 30}\nModel Val-Score: {val_score:.4f}')
        test_score = f1_score(y_test, pipeline.predict(X_test))
        print(f'Model F1-Score: {test_score:.4f}\n\n')
        pipelines.append(pipeline)
        scores_df = scores_df.append({'Model': clf_name, 
                                      'Val_Score': val_score, 
                                      'F1_Score': test_score}, ignore_index=True)
    return pipelines, scores_df
```

I just want to capture a little bit of knowledge from the experienced programmers with discussing things. I was just expecting a suggestion/reference or an efficient way/approach to doing this.

What is an efficient way of making a Pipeline for a Machine Learning Classification Problem?

Comment: have you looked at bagging strategies

Comment: No, Could you provide me any reference link?

Comment: Bagging is a way to improve accuracy.  The challenge is to learn from error or new data and not overfit or learn bias in the classifier.

Comment: Check for variance.  High variance models lead to overfitting.  There is a trade off between model complexity and variance and bias, the more complex the model the less variance and bias.  High variance and low bias means that the function is overshooting the target picking up the noise

Comment: I included a voting classifier.   it selects the best classifier and uses its results.

Answer (score 0):

try voting classifier.  it takes an ensemble strategy to finding an optimum classifier using a voting approach.

```
  # Instantiate lr
  lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=SEED)

  # Instantiate knn
  knn = KNN(n_neighbors=27)

  # Instantiate dt
  dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_leaf=1.3, random_state=SEED)

  # Define the list classifiers
 classifiers = [('Logistic Regression', lr), ('K Nearest Neighbours', knn), ('Classification Tree', dt)]

from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
# Instantiate a VotingClassifier vc 
vc = VotingClassifier(estimators=classifiers)     

# Fit vc to the training set
 vc.fit(X_train, y_train)   

# Evaluate the test set predictions
y_pred = vc.predict(X_test)

# Calculate accuracy score
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print('{:s} : {:.3f}'.format(clf_name, accuracy))
```

try the BaggingClassifier to improve accuracy.  Other bagging classifiers are: AdaBoostClassifer and GradientBoostingRegressor.  At this point you may want to consider using pytorch to overcome the accuracy problem.  I see you have the MLPClassifier which is a neural network but it is not used exclusively and the configuration is not defined.

```
 from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

 SEED=1


 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y,
                                             random_state=SEED)


 dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4, min_samples_leaf=1.6, random_state=SEED)

 bc=BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=dt, n_estimators=300, n_jobs=-1)


 bc.fit(X_train, y_train)   

 # Evaluate the test set predictions
 y_pred = bc.predict(X_test)

 # Calculate accuracy score
 accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
 print('{:s} : {:.3f}'.format(clf_name, accuracy))
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually, a pipeline is built to solve a specific task that requires one or multiple classifiers working jointly. However, in your case, there are many classifiers working independently instead of jointly. If you want to learn more about the pipeline, you can take a look at several examples from [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/transformers/task_summary.html#sequence-classification)

Here is an example of the pipeline for Sentiment Analysis task:

```
>>> from transformers import pipeline

>>> nlp = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")

>>> result = nlp("I hate you")[0]
>>> print(f"label: {result['label']}, with score: {round(result['score'], 4)}")
label: NEGATIVE, with score: 0.9991

>>> result = nlp("I love you")[0]
>>> print(f"label: {result['label']}, with score: {round(result['score'], 4)}")
label: POSITIVE, with score: 0.9999
```